# Responsive pseudo text

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to add text in a pseudo element :`before` the `body`. It seems however I am forced to set the `font-size` which means it isn't responsive.

How can I force the `content:'404'` to be responsive when changing the browser dimensions? I'm I absolutely limited to SVG images?

Result I'm looking for is the 404 text behind content:

[image: 404].

Comment: You can set the font-size to be em. It's more responsive than pixels. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I have, however if I do that I'll have to constantly modify the size  with each responsive break point. This also doesn't take the height into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried with "vw" - [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

```
body::before {
    content: "404";
    font-size: 50vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -25px);
}
```

Comment: Ouhhh, very close. The `vw` unit is indeed the correct unit, I just need to make it remain vertically centered when not changing the browser's height

Comment: I added `top:50%` and modified your translate to `transform:translate(-50%,-50%)` and it's working now. Thanks a bunch

Comment: You're welcome @MPaul, glad for helping